# How to iterate an array based on a maximum count value and not based on the length of the array

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to iterate an array based on a maximum count value and not based on the length of the array. For example, if an array has 6 elements and maximum count of iteration is 7. For example,

```
var arrayData = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var count = 7;

for( var n=0;n<count;n++)
{

    predictValue = arrayData[n];                
}
alert(predictValue);
```

Above code will return value till position 5 i.e F value, if n=6, then it will return `undefined`, I want the counter to start from 0th position that is to read value A if counter n reaches length of `arrayData`.

Comment: for (var n = 0; n < count; n++) { var value = arrayData[n%arrayData.length]; }

Comment: @atomman, why not add that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @DouglasLudlow because imho answers should be more than just a codesnipplet. It should probably link to a site explaining modulus and show why this works. And I dont have the time for that right now. :p

Answer (score 2):

try Modulus:

```
 ...predictValue = arrayData[n % arrayData.length]; ...
```

Comment: Yup, this is what you'd want. No need for if/else, just simple math. 0 % 6 == 0, 1 % 6 == 1,...5 % 6 == 5, 6 % 6 == 0, 7 % 6 == 1,...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
predictValue = arrayData[n] ? arrayData[n] : arrayData[n - count + 1];
```

```js
var arrayData = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var count = 7;

for( var n=0;n<count;n++)
{

    predictValue = arrayData[n] ? arrayData[n] : arrayData[n - count + 1] ;                
}
alert(predictValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use - nested ternary operator**

```js
var arrayData = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
    var count = 7;
    
    for( var n=0;n<count;n++)
    {
    
    predictValue = arrayData[n] ? arrayData[n] : arrayData[n - count + 1];
    
    }
    
    alert(predictValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Length method return length of the array( or string also this depends on the parameter )

for example :

```
for(var i = 0;array.length,i++){
   //Some code goes here 
}
```

So your code should look something like this :

```
var arrayData = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var count = 7;

for( var n=0;n<arrayData.length;n++)
{

predictValue = arrayData[n];

}

alert(predictValue);
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) .

Answer (score 0):

If you asking how to `reiterate` over the `array` once you have reached the end then you would need to do a check:

```
for(var n = 0; n < count; n++) {
    if (n == arrayData.length) {
        n = 0;
    }
    predictValue = arrayData[n];
}
```